# Real world guide on using and/or setting up REST web services?

Tags: php, python, xml, rest, soap

I've only used XML RPC and I haven't really delved into SOAP but I'm trying to find a good comprehensive guide, with real world examples or even a walkthrough of some minimal REST application.

I'm most comfortable with Python/PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few links:

- http://www.infoq.com/articles/webber-rest-workflow
- http://microformats.org/wiki/rest/urls
- http://blog.feedly.com/2009/05/06/best-practices-for-building-json-rest-web-services/
- http://barelyenough.org/blog/2008/05/versioning-rest-web-services/
- http://bitworking.org/news/restful_json/

(I should note, that the last one uses relative url's - a practise I don't like. But the rest of the article is very good, so I linked it anyway.)

Comment: Yeah, the last article is not REST. Don't link to misleading and inaccurate articles. Most browsers/servers use gzip anyway which makes it unnecessary to chop down URIs like that.

Answer (score 1):

I like the examples in the Richardson & Ruby book, "RESTful Web Services" from O'Reilly.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good example with the Google App Engine Documentation. http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/rpc.html. It also talks you through some security aspects of doing REST